# Use Django dumpdata to dump a subset of overall data?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, dumpdata

I'm trying to use dumpdata to generate JSON for a database that is sufficiently large for django to take a long, long time to output. Is there any way to dump only a subset of the fields; say, 100, for testing?

I'm using MySQL and Django 1.0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Selective Dumpdata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313558/django-selective-dumpdata)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A 3rd party django app, [django-test-utils](http://github.com/ericholscher/django-test-utils) contains a [makefixture](http://github.com/ericholscher/django-test-utils/blob/master/test_utils/management/commands/makefixture.py) command implementation which is basically a smarter dumpdata. You can specify exact model names with ID ranges to export (and it will follow related objects)
Example: `manage.py makefixture --format=xml --indent=4 proj.appname.modelname[1:101] > test.xml`

Answer (score 1):

See also [Django Selective Dumpdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313558/django-selective-dumpdata) which suggests [Django Fixture Magic](https://github.com/davedash/django-fixture-magic)