# Django dumpdata by date

Tags: django, date, fixtures, dumpdata

Is there a way or any modules available to do dumpdata of all models filtered by date? For example, between a range of dates or the dates greater|lesser than the given.

[limiting-the-amount-of-fixtures-in-django-dumpdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135832/limiting-the-amount-of-fixtures-in-django-dumpdata) deals with the ID and also the explicit model names as arguments.

I'm not meaning the Django/Python datetime fields. I'm assuming there might be a native support of date and time to keep track when the record is added in the database. And I use postgres.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to limit the dataset by a range of dates.